# google chrome's 'Copy styles' button using browser's API instead

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

In Google chrome they have a the copy styles button feature since [V77](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-77/#copystyles)

But can't figure out how to use it using the Browser's API

I have tried `getComputedStyle` but apparently the result is not what's expected (it has a more styles than needed)

If we compared the result of "Copy styles" available in google chrome dev tools GUI and the browser's `getComputedStyle` for a any element

After "copy styles" the result would look like this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;    
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;    
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);     
box-sizing: inherit;    
position: fixed;    
z-index: 1300;  
right: 0;
bottom: 0; 
top: 0; 
left: 0;
```

While `getComputedStyles` has a lot more than these styles (a whole lot more)

Where I expect to have another API that can copy css just like the
"copy styles" button

Comment: The css you wrote would be helpful... To my understanding, the Copy styles only includes css properties explictly set in CSS. They should be acessable just like any other object attribute, through `copyStyles.property`

Comment: Sorry @Esdeseserdt1976 I added more explanation.